# Return each occurrence of string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a very long string that may contain versions of another string. The  format of the string that I am looking for within the main string will be

```
<umbraco:macro ??? />
```

The ??? Will be different in each case but  I need to get each instance of this string into an array so I can use I csharp code to process.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Am using C# .Net code to run the regex by the way.

Comment: array? Which lang did you prefer?

Comment: did you mean this `@"(?<=:macro\s+).*?(?=\s+/>)"`

Comment: Is this xml?  If so, why not parse the xml?

Comment: Its not xml it is html but this fragment could occur in the middle of text

Comment: Using csharp code to run the regex by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the regex for you:

```
<umbraco:macro (.*?) [\/]>
```

View test cases here: https://regex101.com/r/pY5vB5/1

Then you just need to pull out the stuff in the capture groups.

Comment: Actually I need to return the whole tag fragment (including the opening < and closing /> characters) in each case not just the attributes and inner text.

Comment: @wingyip In that case, just move the capture group to outside. In other words, move the parenthesis outside, `(<umbraco:macro .*? [\/]>)`